# rails test failed: Expected true to be nil or false

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. I've been stuck on Chapter 6.3.2

When running rails test this is the message I get:

FAIL["test_email_addresses_should_be_unique", #, 1.1244590690002951]
 test_email_addresses_should_be_unique#UserTest (1.12s)
        Expected true to be nil or false
        test/models/user_test.rb:56:in `block in '

14/14: [====================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.15905s
14 tests, 30 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

my code for test/models/user_test.rb

```
user_test.rb

require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = ""
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

    test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name = "a" * 51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should not be too long" do
    @user.email = "a" * 244 + "@example.com"
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
    valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org
                         first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
    valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
      @user.email = valid_address
      assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
    end
  end

  test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example.
                           foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"
    end
  end

  test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
  end
end
```

my code for test/models/user_test.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Is it possible this is a result of running:

```
rails console --sandbox
```

earlier I ran sandbox and while running

```
>> duplicate_user.valid?
```

i got false when I should have gotten true.
any help will be much appreciated, Thanks in advance!

in user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
end
```

Comment: can you show the user model

Comment: so inside user.rb I have:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
end
```

i know this looks terrible having trouble with the format in comments

Comment: put it in the question please

Comment: try changing `@user.email.upcase` to just `@user.email` in the test

Comment: if it solved your problem please accept the answer so the question can be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your test fails is because the uniqueness validation is case-sensitive so in order to correct your test you could change **@user.email.upcase** to **@user.email**

Fortunately, `:uniqueness` accepts an option, `:case_sensitive`

so adding this to your model file will also solve your problem

```
 uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

be careful though Active Record uniqueness validation does not guarantee uniqueness at the database level